# Set background of div by javascript from array

Tags: javascript, css

I have an array with names of images and I want to set background using those like this:

```
var deckArray = ['0С.png','0D.png'];
document.getElementById(""+i+"").style.background = "url('"+deckArray[i]+"') no-repeat center center";
```

But it doesn't work. I'm doing this that way because I need to fill some divs. How can I do it?

Comment: can you share your html and js fot the elements in play. I can see a lot of things going wrong

Comment: if not. try ``element.style.backgroundImage = string;``

Comment: Why are you wrapping `i` with `"`? and what do you mean exactly by doesn't work, any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors, just doesn't show me the picture. i think problem is in concatenation, because when i use just 'url("0C.png")' it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're lookings for `.css`

`document.getElementById(""+i+"").css("background-image": "link")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting the for loop:

```
var deckArray = ['0С.png','0D.png'];
for (i = 0; i < deckArray.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById(i).style.background = "url('"+deckArray[i]+"') no-repeat center center"
}
```

Keep in mind that numbers shouldn't be id's so I would have it:

```
document.getElementById("deck"+i);
```

Obviously make sure you update the id's of the actual elements too.

Comment: The problem is in concatenation. When i try this:

    document.getElementById(""+i+"").style.background = "url('0C.png') no-repeat center center"

it works.

Comment: You need to explain or show more of what the problem is. Maybe create a jsfiddle.

Comment: What is "i" though. If "i" is 0, then deckArray[i] will get 0C.png. You should output using console.log or alert to see what deckArray[i] is.

Comment: Sorry bud, didn't get a chance to look at this last thing until now. Did you get it resolved. The problem with your fiddle is that you have a function inside the onload. If you want that it needs to be declared var randomCardNum = function() {...}. https://jsfiddle.net/enm8zjv1/6/ when I click the area it shows the card and puts file numbers in each.